# Magmi v0.7.22 import while image name include "fußballschuhe" "ß" disappear front

Tags: magmi

Magmi v0.7.22 import while image name include "fußballschuhe" "ß"(like "cap kinder weiß-563tjs.jpg", "mundial kinder weiß-442bqx.jpg") disappear front,can't import success.the other image name include english style appear well front.anyone can help me,i use the magmi import product with my site sale eruo country.that Germany Czech Language image name will in that situation.

and i can use the magento back import them all well.the magmi i use can't import the image name that include "weiß"  or other character likely Germany Czech Language.
@Dweeves